# Display formkey in knockoutjs template

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, knockoutjs

I have a phtml template that display the formkey in my html file. Below is how I'm displaying this

```
<form action=""
      method="post"
      id="form-validate-pound"      
      class="form form-cart">

     <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>

      <button type="submit"
       name="click_for_pound_action"
       data-cart-empty=""
       value="click_pound"
       title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Click for Pound')) ?>"
       class="action clear btn btn-yellow" id="click_pound_button">
           <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Click for Pound')) ?>
               <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
           </span>
      </button>
</form>
```

So basically I need to display `<?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>` in my knockoutjs template. Below I need to display it in this html file

```
<form action=""
      method="post"
      id="form-validate-pound"
      class="form form-cart">

  <!-- DISPLAY THE FORMKEY HERE -->

      <button type="submit"
       name="click_for_pound_action"
       data-cart-empty=""
       value="click_pound"
       title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Click for Pound')) ?>"
       class="action clear btn btn-yellow" id="click_pound_button">
      <span>
       <!-- ko i18n: 'Click for Pound'--><!-- /ko -->
         <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
      </span>
   </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the core achieves this:

**Javascript**

```
file: vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment.js:98

getFormKey: function () {
            return window.checkoutConfig.formKey;
}
```

**HTML**

```
file: vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/payment.html:19

<form id="co-payment-form" class="form payments" novalidate="novalidate">
    <input data-bind='attr: {value: getFormKey()}' type="hidden" name="form_key"/>
            ...
</form>
```